# Ionic 4 - router, pages and side menu

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

Can someone help me with my issue? I have one view (map) and side menu with map and other options.

When I start application, map shows but hasn't got menu icon and have map position issue (map is moved some pixels from the top). When I navigate manually to other url (bookings), side bar menu button shows and now I have menu icon on map.

Some code below.

app-routing.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'map', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'map', loadChildren: '../map/map.module#MapPageModule' },
  { path: 'menu', loadChildren: './pages/menu/menu.module#MenuPageModule' },
];
```

menu.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';

import { MenuPage } from './menu.page';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: MenuPage,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'bookings',
        loadChildren: './bookings/bookings.module#BookingsPageModule'
      },
      {
        path: 'help',
        loadChildren: './help/help.module#HelpPageModule'
      },
      {
        path: 'payment',
        loadChildren: './payment/payment.module#PaymentPageModule'
      },
      {
        path: 'profile',
        loadChildren: './profile/profile.module#ProfilePageModule'
      },
      {
        path: 'settings',
        loadChildren: './settings/settings.module#SettingsPageModule'
      }
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    IonicModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes)
  ],
  declarations: [MenuPage]
})
export class MenuPageModule {
}
```

map.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';

import { MapPage } from './map.page';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: MapPage
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    IonicModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes)
  ],
  declarations: [MapPage]
})
export class MapPageModule {
}
```

menu.page.html

```
<ion-menu contentId="content">

    <ion-header>
        <ion-toolbar>
            <ion-title>
                Simple menu
            </ion-title>
        </ion-toolbar>
    </ion-header>

    <ion-content>
        <div>
            <ion-menu-toggle>
                <ion-item routerLink="/map" routerDirection="root" routerLinkActive="active" detail='false'>
                    <ion-icon name="map" slot="start"></ion-icon>
                    <ion-label>
                        Map
                    </ion-label>
                </ion-item>
            </ion-menu-toggle>
        </div>
        <div>
            <ion-menu-toggle>
                <ion-item routerLink="/menu/bookings" routerDirection="root" routerLinkActive="active" detail='false'>
                    <ion-icon name="time" slot="start"></ion-icon>
                    <ion-label>
                        Booking history
                    </ion-label>
                </ion-item>
            </ion-menu-toggle>
        </div>

    </ion-content>

    <ion-footer>
        <div>
            <ion-menu-toggle>
                <ion-item routerLink="/login" routerDirection="root" routerLinkActive="active" detail='false'>
                    <ion-icon name="contact" slot="start"></ion-icon>
                    <ion-label>
                        Sign in
                    </ion-label>
                </ion-item>
            </ion-menu-toggle>
        </div>
    </ion-footer>

</ion-menu>

<ion-router-outlet id="content" main></ion-router-outlet>
```

map.page.html

```
<ion-header no-border no-padding>
    <ion-toolbar>
        <ion-buttons slot="start">
            <ion-menu-button color="primary"></ion-menu-button>
        </ion-buttons>
        <ion-searchbar animated></ion-searchbar>
    </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content fullscreen>
    <div class="map" id="map"></div>
</ion-content>
```

menu/bookings/page.html

```
<ion-header>
    <ion-toolbar color="transparent">
        <ion-buttons slot="start">
            <ion-menu-button color="tertiary"></ion-menu-button>
        </ion-buttons>
        <ion-title>Bookings</ion-title>
    </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>

</ion-content>
```

**And some screenshots**

*First time map view with no menu icon and map position issue*
[image: First time map view with no menu icon and map position issue]

*Manually entered /menu/bookings route and menu is showed*
[image: Manually entered /menu/bookings route and menu is showed]

*Navigate from menu to map shows icon but white stripe is still on view*
[image: Navigate from menu to map shows icon but white stripe is still on view]

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like `MAP` is a child of `MENU`. Is this by design?

What it looks like is happening is the `map.html` is loading 1st, but `menu.html` is only loading when you navigate away.

You need to "land" on the `menu.html` page for it to load, then either navigate manually to the map or redirect to it.

in `app.component.ts` you can add a router navigate for once the project loads.

```
initializeApp() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      this.statusBar.styleDefault();
      this.splashScreen.hide();

      this.router.navigate(['menu', 'map']);

    });
  }
```

or maybe in `menu.module.ts` add a redirect then erase the path in your web browser after `http://localhost:8100` or after whatever number you see after `http://localhost:`

```
import { MenuPage } from './menu.page';

const routes: Routes = [

  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'menu/map',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },

  {
    path: '',
    component: MenuPage,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'bookings',
        loadChildren: './bookings/bookings.module#BookingsPageModule'
      },
```

I hope this helps you solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, for some reason, your menu is not available. maybe you could try do do this (in `map.page.ts`):

```
import { MenuController } from '@ionic/angular';
export class Map{
    [your code]
    ionViewDidEnter() //executed automaticly when you enter in the page
    {
        this.menu.enable(true,"yourMenuId")
    }
}
```

If it didn't fix your problem, at least it will problably give you an error message that will tell you what's wrong